# VIM not able to use <tab> key in mapping

Tags: vim, mapping

I try to make this mapping:
`nnoremap <leader>b :b <tab>`
but it does not work.

It prints this string in the command line:
`:b ^I`

It seems that I don't use  in the proper way.

Comment: I found the answer in Vi and Vim Stack Exchange: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13507/how-can-i-trigger-commandline-tab-completion-from-a-mapping

Answer (score 0):

The key you type to start command-line completion is defined by the option `:help 'wildchar'`. It is set to `<Tab>` by default, which can't be used in a macro and thus inside a mapping:

> The character is not recognized when used inside a macro.  See 'wildcharm' for that.

You need a proxy for that: the aforementioned `:help 'wildcharm'`.

```
set wildcharm=<C-z>
nnoremap <leader>b :b <C-z>
```